# JSON data error says data is null when it's not?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

**QUESTION:**

I am currently trying to map meteorite landings data on a map in D3.

I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError:

`Cannot read property 'coordinates' of null index.html 89`

I believe the way I get the JSON data is correct and I checked with a console.log that `d.geometry` is indeed not null.

What have I done wrong ?

---

**CODE:**

```
 <script>

        // Map: https://codepen.io/manishgolcha/post/world-map-using-d3-js

        var jMap = $(".map"),
            height = jMap.height(),
            width = jMap.width(),
            mapJsonUrl = 'https://ucarecdn.com/8e1027ea-dafd-4d6c-bf1e-698d305d4760/world110m2.json',
           svg = d3.select(".map").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var getProjection = function() {
         var scale = 1,
             offset = [ width / 2, height / 2 ],
             projection = d3.geoEquirectangular().scale( scale ).rotate( [0,0] ).center([0,5]).translate( offset ),
             bounds = mercatorBounds( projection ),
             scaleExtent;

            scale = width / (bounds[ 1 ][ 0 ] - bounds[ 0 ][ 0 ]);
            scaleExtent = [ scale, 10 * scale ];

            projection
              .scale( scaleExtent[ 0 ] );

          return projection;
        },

        mercatorBounds = function(projection) {
          var maxlat = 83,
              yaw = projection.rotate()[ 0 ],
              xymax = projection( [ -yaw + 180 - 1e-6, -maxlat ] ),
              xymin = projection( [ -yaw - 180 + 1e-6, maxlat ] );

           return [ xymin, xymax ];
        };


        d3.json(mapJsonUrl, function (error, worldJson) {
            if (error) throw error;

          var projection = getProjection(),
              path = d3.geoPath().projection( projection );

          svg.selectAll( 'path.land' )
              .data( topojson.feature( worldJson, worldJson.objects.countries ).features )
              .enter().append( 'path' )
              .attr( 'class', 'land' )
              .attr( 'd', path );

            d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/meteorite-strike-data.json", function(data) {

                const geoData = data.features;

                console.log(data.features[0].geometry);

                svg.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(geoData)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("cx", (d) => projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]])[0])
                  .attr("cy", (d) => projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]])[1])
                  .attr("r", d.properties.mass)
                  .style("fill", "orange")
                  .style("opacity", 0.8);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll not refactor your code (which has some other problems), but only explain the problems directly related to your issue:

First, there are lots of `null` values for the `geometries`. Thus, you have to check them first:

```
.attr("cx", (d) => {
    if (d.geometry) return projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0],
        d.geometry.coordinates[1]
    ])[0]
})
```

Besides that, you don't have a scale for the circles. You can't do this:

```
.attr("r", d.properties.mass)
```

Unless you want a circle with a radius of thousands of pixels. Thus, I created one using `scale.Sqrt`:

```
var meteorScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .domain([0, d3.max(geoData, d=>+d.properties.mass)])
    .range([0, 30]);
```

Here is your updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmmgOK?editors=1000

Answer (score 0):

Geometry is null actually , you can see it in json

[image]